# Pointers & Classes, Output

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, methods, heap-memory

Thanks in advance,

So, i'm processing classes with **pointers** included, last ones are the topic

If i have classes like the following instance, i need some push to **display** the data which the pointer  (Heap pointer) of the class aims, knowing that it aims (points) to the **member value** in the **C-tor** (member).

Some help for correcting the error.

I added a child class just for **details** of inheritance, if you can add some detail informations about (in case there are).

I'm getting values 7405304 For the Mother Class & 4997952 for the Child Class (not 9 & 99 for the respective expected outputs), if i can add, why does this happen ?

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

class Mother {
 public:
  Mother(int member) {
    mem = new int; /*Heap Ptr*/

    mem = &member;

    std::cout << "C-tor" << std::endl;
  }

  ~Mother() {
    delete mem;
    *mem = 0;

    std::cout << "D-tor" << std::endl;
  }

  virtual void display() const {
    std::cout
        << *mem
        << std::endl; /*What should i put here ? I've an unexpected value */
  }

 private:
  int* mem = 0;
};

class Child : public Mother {
 public:
  Child(int a) : Mother(a) {}
  ~Child() {}
};

void data(Mother const* m) {
  m->display();
}
int main() {
  int a(9), b(99);

  Child child(a);
  Mother mother(b);

  data(&mother);
  data(&child);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact error you're getting.

Comment: `mem = &member;` This address becomes invalid as soon as the constructor returns. You probably wanted `*mem = member;` instead.

Comment: Indeed ! that solves my problem. @dxiv

Comment: Before you hit the next bit of nasty, save yourself some time and read about [the Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and its most excellent friends.

Comment: Before you hit your next bit of vainglory, it don't solicit a whole off topic to solve the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just several comments on your code. Most importantly, it it's all good with inheritance. Declararing `display` function as virtual is not needed as this assumes that you will re-define it in `Child`, which you do not do. In short, all the ills come from the pointer `mem`. In destructor for Mother class you have this:

```
delete mem;
*mem = 0;
```

which logically doesn't makes sense. After `delete mem` the pointer doesn't exist, so next line de-references freshly deleted pointer. Lets follow the lifecycle of the pointer `mem`. It is first created in `private`, then it is re-assigned a new pointer created via `new int`, then it is re-assigned again to `&member` (which means that `delete mem` in destructor will not be looking at `new int` pointer, but rather at `&member`). If you fix these issues like so

```
class Mother {
 public:
  Mother(int member) {
    *mem = member;

    std::cout << "C-tor" << std::endl;
  }

  ~Mother() {
    delete mem;

    std::cout << "D-tor" << std::endl;
  }

  void display() const {
    std::cout
        << *mem
        << std::endl; /*What should i put here ? I've an unexpected value */
  }

 private:
  int * mem = new int;
};

class Child : public Mother {
 public:
  Child(int a) : Mother(a) {}
  ~Child() {}
};

void data(Mother const * m) {
  m->display();
}


int main() {
  int a(9), b(99);

  Child child(a);
  Mother mother(b);

  data(&mother);
  data(&child);

  return 0;
}
```

you should get the correct output.